# How to implement drag and Drop on Mobile Browser in Blazor

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I have a working solution where Drag and Drop works fine on a Computer using the draggable=true on div, as well as @ondragstart and @ondragend.

I can see that there are libraries e.g., hammer.js and interactive.js that can provide touch gestures etc for mobile browsers, but how do I utilize these within my Blazor project?

Does anyone have an example to share?

Comment: Maybe this is what you need? https://www.vanderwaal.eu/mini-projecten/draggable-div-with-touch

Comment: That doesn't work on mobile devices with touch events.

Comment: Weird. It did the last time I checked with an ipad.... Will check it again in a couple of days. Sorry about that.

Comment: Fixed it... It works again

Comment: Thank you. This works now, but I'm actually looking for a drag and drop, i.e., I also need to catch the "enter" and "leave" touch events. Blazor docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0) points to a ontouchenter and ontouchleave, but I can't get these working.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to prevent scoll in mobile devices during drag and drop in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67498921/how-to-prevent-scoll-in-mobile-devices-during-drag-and-drop-in-blazor) to start from. It still has a drawback with mobile devices that wants to scroll the page at the same time as you drag and drop, but it might help you to get started.